# How to pass pass data via href on Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How can I make the list link to other pages?

[image]

**Pscontroller:**

```
  public function show()
  {
      $ps = DB::table('ps')->get();

      return view('viewps', ['ps' => $ps]);

  }

public function view($id)
{
        $ps = Ps::find($id);

        // show the view and pass to it
        return view ('view')->with('ps', $ps);

}
```

**routes:**

```
Route::get('/viewps', 'PsController@show');
Route::get('/viewps/{id}', 'PsController@view');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href={{ route('/viewps/'.$single_ps->id)}}
```

Comment: While answers are always appreciated, it really helps to provide some information about how your code solves the problem at hand. Not everyone may be familiar with your exact coding logic, but may understand your general *approach* or *concept*. To help improve your answer, please provide some [**context surrounding it**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762), and see the help article on [**writing great answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some tips on how to make your answers count :)

Answer (score 0):

Give name to route like below

```
Route::get('/viewps/{id}', 'PsController@view')->name('viewps');
```

Now wherever you wanna generate link do like this

```
<a href={{ route('viewps',['id'=>$single_ps->id])}}
```

In this way if you change endpoint of route you have not to change the router path in all files